# Print document in c# console app

Tags: c#, console-application, printdocument

I need to print any doc type in console app, i tried 
using System.Drawing.Printing, but it could not be found in VS.
`System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument printDocument = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();`

Comment: "could not be found in VS"  then add a reference to System.Drawing then. I dunno if that will help you in the longrun though, digging now.

Comment: This worked for me: in the Solution Explorer tab, right click on References and select "Add Reference...". Then click Assemblies, Framework, and scroll down until you see System.Drawing. Click the checkbox next to it, then click OK. 
But now i don't know how to reference wanted document to be printed?Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you want to let windows open any document while calling the default applications 'print' function (like right click in explorer - print)  or do you want to handle the document yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(filePath);
    info.Verb = "Print";
    info.CreateNoWindow = true;
    info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    Process.Start(info);
```