# Sending a file to printer queue with C# ignores print settings

Tags: c#, printing

I need to print files from within a console application. I've found an interesting [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33260285/12326687).

When i copy it from a c# console application it prints in colour.

```
File.Copy("file.pdf", @"\\path\to\printer");
```

When copying the pdf manually to the printer queue, it prints correctly in black-white.

The printer is set up to print in black-white setting. So it seems to my, it's just ignoring the printer settings.

Is there anything I can do in code to fix it or is it a printer thing?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51926369/print-document-in-c-sharp-console-app) is interesting solution, maybe works better.

Comment: Seems like it does send file to a default printer. I have two different "endpoints" for one printer(different papers) and need to target these.